# how to change date format in ionic 3

Tags: angular, ionic3

this i my code. i want to change the date format. it showing  Fri Feb 14 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) this format but i want 14-02-2020. how to get this. please help me guys.

.html file

```
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>From date {{selectedDate}} </ion-label>
  </ion-item>

  <ionic-calendar-date-picker (onSelect)="dateSelected($event)" 
  [(ngModel)]="selectedDate" ngDefaultControl displayFormat="DD-MM-YYYY"></ionic-calendar-date-picker>   



  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>To date {{selectedDate1}} </ion-label>
  </ion-item>

  <ionic-calendar-date-picker displayFormat="DD/MM/YYYY" (onSelect)="dateSelected1($event)" 
  [(ngModel)]="selectedDate1" ngDefaultControl displayFormat="DD-MM-YYYY"></ionic-calendar-date-picker>  

</ion-content>
```

.ts file

dateSelected($event)

{

```
this.selectedDate=$event;

// moment().format('DD-MM-YYYY')

//  this.dateSelected(moment().format('DD/MM/YYYY')); 

 alert($event);
```

}

dateSelected1($event)

{

```
this.selectedDate1=$event;

 moment().format('DD-MM-YYYY');

 alert($event);
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/2.14.1/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var ds = "Fri Feb 14 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)";
    var date = moment(new Date(ds.substr(0, 16)));
    console.log(date.format("DD-MM-YYYY"));
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do as mentioned below:

```
    const formattedDate = moment(this.selectedDate1).format('DD-MM-YYYY');
    console.log(formattedDate);
```

This will print the formatted date as "19-02-2020"

Comment: i'm selecting the dates from calendar then it appears on screen after selecting. the date format is showing (Fri Feb 14 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0530) this. so i want to change date format for all . when i select any date from calendar then it should be in a DD-MM-YYYY format.      how to get this?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UsljN.png       here is my screenshot.  now i change the date format of this calendar view

Answer (score 0):

you can use this in your view

```
{{valueDate | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy'}}
```

Comment: it's working in this case an dit helped me  {{ date|  date: 'dd-MM-yyyy'  }}